# How do I get $(/bin/printf -6) to return -6 and not think -6 is an option

Tags: bash, shell, printf, busybox

I have a bash shell script which has the line:

```
g=$(/bin/printf ${i})
```

when `${i}` contains something like `-6`, `printf` thinks its being passed an option. It does not recognize the option so produces an error.

if wrap `${i}` in quotes, `printf` still thinks its being passed an option.

```
g=$(/bin/printf "${i}")
```

if I escape the quotes, variable `$g` then holds "`-6`" which is not what I want either.

```
g=$(/bin/printf \"${i}\")
```

Is there away to escape the dash (-).

printf is a BusyBox app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if you called `printf` with an actual format string?

```
$ printf "%d\n" -6
-6
$ /sbin/busybox printf "%d\n" -6
-6
$
```

This works with both GNU coreutils' and busybox' printf, apparently.

Comment: this works - though I think there is a reason the script does not do this already. As it could just simple use echo. However it works for now, but if anyone as a better solution, I would be interested.

Comment: Well, if it is just a question of %d... then you could just do `g=$i` and be done without invoking another process at all.

Comment: ${i} could be anything, number, string etc. Any value starting with '-' will cause printf to fail.

Comment: Exactly. So we have now solved the issue of how to get printf(1) to handle a negative number in `$i`. However, the issue of how your script arrives at that value for `$i` and how it proceeds with the new `$g` is an entirely different beast.

Answer (score 13):

Most GNU programs support using `--` as a delimiter to tell the program that all further arguments are not options. For instance

```
$ printf -- -6
-6
```

Comment: thanks. That would work, but my printf is a BusyBox version, which does not support that option. any other ideas.

Comment: @Andrew In that case a format string as ndim suggested is probably the way to go. I've added the busybox tag to your question so this is obvious for future readers.

Comment: It looks like sufficiently new versions of busybox also support `--`: `busybox printf -- -6` outputs `-6` with busybox 1.27.2

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
printf -- -6
```

Comment: "Should"? If `-6` is a constant and can be audited to behave correctly when interpreted as a format string, sure. If it's coming from a variable, an explicit format string should be provided: `printf '%s' -6`, or even `printf -- '%s' -6`.

Answer (score 0):

If you feed a non-numeric argument in this way, you get an error message:

```
$ busybox printf "%d" "a"
a: conversion error
-1
```

But you can use `%s` and it will work for both numeric and non-numeric arguments (as long as you don't need to do any formatting):

```
$ busybox printf "%s" "a"
a
$ busybox printf "%s" -6
-6
```

If you're not using the formatting features of `printf` and you need to output the value without a newline, busybox's `echo` command supports `-n`:

```
$ busybox echo -n "a"
a
$ busybox echo -n -6
-6
```